# operator== in C++ struct

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I'm trying to define an == operator in a structure:

```
typedef struct _tBScan {
    QString strQuadpackNumbers;
    uint uintBegin, uintEnd;
    bool operator==(const struct _tBScan& a, const struct _tBScan& b) {
        return (a.strQuadpackNumbers.compare(b.strQuadpackNumbers) == 0 &&
                a.uintBegin == b.uintBegin && a.uintEnd == b.uintEnd);
    }
} tBScan;
```

This won't compile, I get:

```
C2804: binary 'operator ==' has too many parameters
C2333: '_tBScan::operator ==' error in function: declaration: skipping function body
```

I'm using Qt 5.9.2 and MSVC 2015, I need to define this so I can use the **QList** compare function.

Comment: Make it a non-member function. Besides the two parameter, member function requires an instance to be called.

Comment: @songyuanyao, can you explain more, it has to be defined as a method in the structure as the its used in QList<tBScan>

Comment: When defining operator in class, first operand is `this`, i.e. current object. You can move it out of class or keep it as member, remove one of the arguments and use `this` instead.

Comment: or memeber with one argument. `operator==` has the left operand and the right operand, yours has 3 in total, which isnt right. `tbScan.operator==( a,b)` when you want `tbScan.operator==(a);`

Comment: @SPlatten It doesn't have to be a member, unless `QList` uses `x.operator==(y)` instead of `x == y` for some unholy reason.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, the QList compare function requires an overload == operator.

Comment: @SPlatten But it doesn't require it to be a member function. This compendium might be worth to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421715#4421715

Comment: No need for `typedef struct ss {} sss` in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overloading an binary operator as a member function, the first parameter is `this` pointer. In the signature you have defined the `operator==`, it will take 3 arguments. However, it can only take two.

In you case I would recommend making it a non-member function.

```
typedef struct _tBScan {
    QString strQuadpackNumbers;
    uint uintBegin, uintEnd;
} tBScan;

bool operator==(const struct _tBScan& a, const struct _tBScan& b) {
        return (a.strQuadpackNumbers.compare(b.strQuadpackNumbers) == 0 &&
                a.uintBegin == b.uintBegin && a.uintEnd == b.uintEnd);
}
```

When you overload the, let's say, `operator@` the expression `_tBScan @ _smt` is resolved into.

```
_tBScan.operator@(_smt);
```

When it's not a member function the expression is resolved into

```
operator@(_tBScan, _smt);
```

So the compiler searches the overload of either of them.

Comment: How is the relation ship between "this" and the operator defined when it is not a method of the structure?

Comment: @SPlatten see the edit.